# How to output value based on whether current date is before October or not?

Tags: excel, vba

I want VarYear equal 2021 if the current date is before October 1 and 2022 if not.

```vb
Dim NowDate As Variant
Dim NowYear As Var
NowDate = Date
NowYear = Year(NowDate)
Dim VarYear As Variant
If NowYear < 10 / 1 Then
    VarYear = NowYear
ElseIf NowYear >= 10 / 1 Then
    VarYear = NowYear + 1
End If
```

Comment: You're using `Year` but I think you meant `Month`.

Comment: `10 / 1`? What are you trying to do with that statement? If it is 1st October then what you are doing is incorrect..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or a slightly more general approach using [`Month`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/month-function):

```
If Month(Date) < 10 Then
   VarYear = Year(Date)
Else
   VarYear = Year(Date) + 1
End If
```

Comment: ++ Yes. Even though the user did not mention the year and said only 1st oct, it is better to include the year else this code will give different result (other than 2022) if run on say 1/11/2020 or 1/11/2022 or any other year... :D

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to have VarYear equal 2021 if the current date is before October 1 and 2022 if the date is after October 1

Is this what you are trying?

```
If Date < DateSerial(2021, 10, 1) Then
    VarYear = 2021
Else
    VarYear = 2022
End If

MsgBox VarYear
```

Comment: Sorry for not being specific, but the output / input can't be year specific. I think the other comments are what I am looking for. Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 0):

This will work with every year. Nothing hardcoded except October:

```
Option Explicit
Const OCTOBER = 10

Sub test()
  Debug.Print (ReturnNextYearIfPastSeptember())
End Sub

Function ReturnNextYearIfPastSeptember()
  Dim NowDate As Date
  Dim NowMonth As Integer
  Dim VarYear As Integer
    
  NowDate = Now()
  NowMonth = Month(NowDate)
  VarYear = Year(NowDate)
  If NowMonth >= OCTOBER Then VarYear = VarYear + 1
  ReturnNextYearIfPastSeptember = VarYear
End Function
```